Empty output of tcpdump --list-interfaces
Executing tcpdump --list-interfaces returns an empty response:
root@ds-manager-2:~# tcpdump --list-interfaces
root@ds-manager-2:~#

Here's the output of ifconfig:
root@ds-manager-2:~# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::1889:94ff:fea1:8b8a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1a:89:94:a1:8b:8a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 60  bytes 11775 (11.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20  bytes 1364 (1.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.78.88  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.78.255
        inet6 fe80::68dd:64ff:fe87:a698  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 6a:dd:64:87:a6:98  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6645  bytes 963906 (963.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 20  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1618  bytes 205343 (205.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 36  bytes 4032 (4.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 36  bytes 4032 (4.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

And ip a (same information as above):
root@ds-manager-2:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0@if149: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1a:89:94:a1:8b:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.178.1/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1889:94ff:fea1:8b8a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1@if150: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6a:dd:64:87:a6:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.78.88/24 brd 192.168.78.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::68dd:64ff:fe87:a698/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

About the machine: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS running in a Proxmox (PVE) server.
PS: tcpdump is not working in general - produces empty output with any combination of arguments.
